# Using Google maps geocoder with address and component restrictions for country

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have a field on my form that is using the google autocomplete feature

```
new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location, { types: ['geocode'] });
```

but if the user doesn't select a dropdown from the autocomplete I need google maps geocoder to search when the form is submitted. I want my user to select either a street, town, city, neighborhood, etc anywhere in the world!

```js
var navbarGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
navbarGeocoder.geocode({
      'address': location.value
    }, function(results, status) {
```

But now I want to be able to limit the geocoder to the US (street, neighborhood, city, town, etc.) with the componentRestriction of the country (US), but when I try this below it just hangs!

```js
var navbarGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
navbarGeocoder.geocode({
  'address': location.value
}, {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: ' US'
  }
}, function(results, status) {

  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something
  }

});
```

Is there a proper way to add the component restriction and still have the address field? Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering) to the google site for doc, is there a field in the component restrictions that acts like the address field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking over the documentation you supplied I think your problem might actually be pretty simple - though I have yet to test it myself. Anyway, if you scroll up to the "Geocoding requests" section you'll see the following code.

```
{
 address: string,
 location: LatLng,
 placeId: string,
 bounds: LatLngBounds,
 componentRestrictions: GeocoderComponentRestrictions,
 region: string
}
```

So, I think you just need to put the componentRestrictions field in the same array as the actual address.
Let me know if it helps :)

So instead of what you posted, try this...

```
var navbarGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
navbarGeocoder.geocode({ 
    'address': location.value, 
    componentRestrictions: { 
        country: ' US' 
    } 
},
```

Comment: Hi ya I saw this, but not sure how to use it inside the geocode function call

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

below is the code snippet!

```js
navbarGeocoder.geocode({
      address: location.value,
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: ' US'
      }
    }, function(results, status) {
```